# How can I access / query page elements with Watir-Webdriver while file uploading is in progress?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, file-upload, block, watir-webdriver

I am trying to automate some file upload jobs with Watir-webdriver and Chrome / Phantomjs.
My code sample:

```
b.file_field(:name => "upload").set(File.expand_path(filename))
b.button(:name=>"upload_button").click
Watir::Wait.until(3*3600){ 
 binding.pry;
 b.link(:text=>/Click here to continue/).present?
}
```

When my script clicks on the upload button, uploading begins and I get to the waiting statement, I get a Pry session to manipulate the variables / page elements. I would like to find out how to read a "span" element on the page b.span(:id=>"percent") which hold the information about how many % of the uploading process is done. However when I try to access any page element I get nothing, but an infinite wait.